# What is the difference between fastened and stabilized?

Tags: meaning, terminology

To be more specific, fixed exchange rate, here, fixed which means fastened. But how am I suppose to explain the difference between fixed or fastened and stabilized?

Comment: The whole question of exchange rate regimes falls outside the scope of this site but you will find numerous explanations online, at sites such as:      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange-rate_regime                             https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevehanke/2018/09/21/to-stabilize-the-world-stabilize-the-usdeuro-exchange-rate/

Comment: Questions about specialized terminology are best answered by specialists in the field, not English teachers; this might be on-topic at [Economics.SE].

Answer (score 1):

**Stabilization** refers to measures taken to prevent wide fluctuations in a value.

**Fixing** refers to making something unable to move physically or, by figurative extension, unable to change value.

**Fastening** refers to attaching something to something else.  It can move physically only if the other thing moves, or by figurative extension, it can change value only if the other thing changes value.